# React Saga Yield call does not finish before next code is run

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a react saga code here which does not run in sequence:

```
yield put({ type: 'SHOW_LOADER', loading: 'workflowobject' }) #yield to initiate the loader
const states = yield call(() => axiosInstance.get(`/workflow-object/state/list/${action.workflow_id}/${action.workflow_object_id}/`))

const newState = states.data.map(item => ({    // some operation to shape my data , might this be the issue?
    iteration: item.iteration,
    ...item.state
}));

yield put({ type: "STORE_WORKFLOW_DATA", payload: newState , fetch: 'workflowobject' , label: 'states'})

.....
bunch more of yields here
.....
yield put({ type: 'HIDE_LOADER', loading: 'workflowobject' }) #yield to change loader state
```

The problem here is that the `HIDE_LOADER` gets called before some inbetween operations end , leading to a error found in my component

Here is my entire code snippet:

## Saga

```
// This code loads the transitions and states for the detail page //
export function* workerWorkflowObjectDetail(action) {
    try{
    yield put({ type: 'SHOW_LOADER', loading: 'workflowobject' })
    // clears the object states
    yield put({ type: 'CLEAR_OBJECT_STATES' })
    // store workflow_id
    yield put({ type: "STORE_WORKFLOW_DATA", payload: action.workflow_id , fetch: 'workflowobject' , label: 'workflow_id'})
    const transitions = yield call(axiosInstance.get , `/workflow-object/transition/list/${action.workflow_id}/${action.workflow_object_id}/`)
    
    // store transitions
    yield put({ type: "STORE_WORKFLOW_DATA", payload: transitions.data, fetch: 'workflowobject' , label: 'transitions'})
    const newStateMap = {}
    transitions.data.forEach(transition => {
        if (transition.is_done) {
            newStateMap[transition.source_state] = done_class
            newStateMap[transition.destination_state] = selected_class
        } else if (transition.is_cancelled) {
            newStateMap[transition.destination_state] = cancelled_class
        } else {
            newStateMap[transition.destination_state] = default_class
        }
    });
   
    // store state_class_mapping
    yield put({ type: "STORE_WORKFLOW_DATA", payload: newStateMap, fetch: 'workflowobject' , label: 'state_class_mapping'})
    const states = yield call(axiosInstance.get, `/workflow-object/state/list/${action.workflow_id}/${action.workflow_object_id}/`)
    const newState = states.data.map(item => ({
        iteration: item.iteration,
        ...item.state
    }));
  
    // stores states
    yield put({ type: "STORE_WORKFLOW_DATA", payload: newState, fetch: 'workflowobject' , label: 'states'})
  
    // stores object_id
    yield put({ type: "STORE_WORKFLOW_DATA", payload: action.workflow_object_id, fetch: 'workflowobject' , label: 'object_identifier'})
    
    // stores current_state
    const current_state = yield call(axiosInstance.get,`/workflow-object/current-state/${action.workflow_id}/${action.workflow_object_id}/`)
    yield put({ type: "STORE_WORKFLOW_DATA", payload: current_state.data, fetch: 'workflowobject' , label: 'current_state'})
    
    //  stores current iteration
    const current_iteration = yield call(axiosInstance.get,`/workflow-object/current-iteration/${action.workflow_id}/${action.workflow_object_id}/`)
    yield put({ type: "STORE_WORKFLOW_DATA", payload: current_iteration.data, fetch: 'workflowobject' , label: 'current_iteration'})
    yield put({ type: 'HIDE_LOADER', loading: 'workflowobject' })
} catch(err){
 console.log(err)
}
    if (action.message) {
        yield put({ type: "CREATE_MESSAGE", message: action.message })
    }
}
```

## Reducer

```
// Helpers
const storeData = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.fetch) {
        case 'workflowobject': return loadWorkflowObject(state, action)
      
    }
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'STORE_WORKFLOW_DATA': return storeData(state, action);
        case 'CLEAR_OBJECT_STATES': return clearObjectStates(state, action);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per `redux-saga` [documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/), `call(fn, ...args)` function should be provided with either a normal or a Generator function.

```js
yield call(() => axiosInstance.get(`/workflow-object/state/list/${action.workflow_id}/${action.workflow_object_id}/`))
```

From you code it looks like the first parameter is neither a normal function that is returning a Promise nor a  Generator function. If the result is not an Iterator object nor a Promise, the middleware will immediately return that value back to the saga, so that it can resume its execution synchronously. As per my understanding this could be the issue.

So instead of providing the arrow function which is calling the API, try providing this way,

```js
yield call(axiosInstance.get, `/workflow-object/state/list/${action.workflow_id}/${action.workflow_object_id}/`)
```

Hope this helps in resolving the issue which you are facing.

Comment: Hey there , thank you for answeing my question , i have tried the solution above however  it seems as though the code is still not working. One Issues is that my hide_loader shows up twice , once prematurely which cause the worker to 'rerun'

Comment: From the saga code wise it's looking fine. Have you checked the `Network` in browser console, whether the API is being called twice? If so, then you might have to check from where the saga action is being triggered

Comment: Hey sorry for the late comment , yep i checked it seems as though my componnet is mounting twice which is weird

Comment: It seems as though the component is mounting twice. I have changed the yield to takeLatest instead , and it works. However  this solution seems breakable

Comment: Oh, because of this component, `HIDE_LOADER` is being called twice. And What do you mean by this seems breakable.?

Comment: Cancelling the previous yield to run the new one felt abit off to me , was thinking what might happen if lets say the first yield completes exactly the same time as the second yield was called

Comment: Even if the previous yield gets successful, then also there'll not be any problem I could see as the subsequent calls gets data and then your component will not break if the data is as you expected. But then there'll be small discrepancy in the UI. This is very a rare scenario.